# Why don't Saiyans age?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

I have seen many *Dragon Ball* series like *Dragon Ball*, *Dragon Ball Z*, *Dragon Ball GT*. One thing remains same is that Saiyans never look aged.
The last episode of *Dragon Ball GT* shows **Pan** as a grandma, but **Goku** was looking as young as he was in *Dragon Ball Z*. Why don't Saiyans age?

Comment: What do you mean? They clearly do age. Goku being the best example of them all. Goku was a little squirt at the beginning of DB, then after his training at Kami's lookout he was a tall squirt and then at the start of DBZ he ages further looking like a real father-like figure.

Comment: About the last episode of Dragon Ball GT: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/19816/what-happened-to-goku-after-he-left-the-earth-at-the-end-of-dragon-ball-gt It seems that your assumption is flawed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To my knowledge, they do age, just very slowly in adulthood. This is a genetic trait, I assume, to reach longer duration of physical demands. They are designed to be fighters, and longevity of a lifespan is only practical. Vegeta confirmed this towards the end of DBZ: "So they can fight longer".

From a quick Google search:

> According to the Daizenshuu, Saiyan's lifespan is about the same as an average Human (70 to 90 years, with exceptions, of course), but keep in their peak longer. Unlike Humans, Saiyans remain in their youth and prime much longer. As explained by Vegeta near the end of Dragon Ball Z, they stay young longer because they live for and are built for battle

<sup>From [Saiyan](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Saiyan) article on Dragon Ball wiki. (Visit the link for more examples, and a more definitive explanation).</sup>

Something else to consider: they stay in their prime longer because they are full Saiyans, whereas Pan is only quarter Saiyan.

Answer (score 1):

I just have to add something else: 
Goku shrunk back to being a little kid during DB GT, right? And if I remember right, he never got the chance to grow back right away but grew up naturally.
Might add as to why he looked the same as he was in DBZ when Pan found him.